# $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$ are not isomorphic as linear orders.

Tags: order-theory

**Informal argument**
So, we know that $\mathbb{R}$ with its usual topology is connected, and of course $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ is not. Any $``$supposed" isomorphism *should* grant us a homeomorphism from $\mathbb{R}$ with its usual topology to $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ with the topology it inherits from $\mathbb{R}$. So we conclude that they can't be isomorphic.

**More Formal Argument**
Suppose a bijection $i: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$ is such that $\forall x \forall y: x<y \longrightarrow f(x)<f(y)$, and additionally, $\forall a \forall b: a<b \longrightarrow f^{-1}(a)<f^{-1}(b)$. Extract a subsets $\Psi$ and $\xi$ of $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ such that: $$\Psi = \{x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\} \mid x<-\frac{1}{n} \forall n\in \mathbb{N} \}$$
$$
\xi = \{x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\} \mid x>\frac{1}{n} \forall n \in \mathbb{N}\}
$$
It is clear that $\Psi \cup \xi = \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$. It is also the case that $\Psi$, $\xi$ are open in the topology that $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$. Since $i^{-1}$ is an order preserving bijection, $i^{-1}$ grants us that $\mathbb{R}$ is the union of two disjoint sets: $i^{-1}(\Psi) \cup i^{-1}(\xi)$. It follows that the preimage of $\Psi$, $\xi$ are open in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ is the union of two disjoint open sets, a contradiction. 
**My question**
Is there a way to *avoid* talking about topological notions of connectedness, or at least phrase connectedness in the language of linear orders? This is an extracurricular problem from my course in **set theory and logic** and it feels as if I'm cheating.

For example, we have the notion elementarily equivalence. If two linear orders are isomorphic then they are elementarily equivalent. The contrapositive gives us if two linear orders are not elementarily equivalent, then they are not isomorphic. So I guess, my real question is: **does there exist a sentence $\phi$ in the language of linear orders that says something about connectedness**? I mean surely $(\mathbb{R},<)$ satisfies the axioms of *dense linear orders*, **does  $(\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}, <)$  $\models \forall x \forall y \exists z (x<z<y)$**? (I believe it does). What sort of **sentence** should I use?
**Edit**
We desire to use the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is a *complete* linear order, in that every subset that is bounded above, has a least upper bound. $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ does not have this property, as Goos's answer shows. Thus, they are not isomorphic as linear orders.

Comment: You shouldn't need to bring topology in to it. I think the notion you are looking for is *completeness* - in $\mathbb R$, every bounded-below set has a greatest lower bound.

Comment: @Alex: Your edit overran mine; and I think [order-theory] is better than [logic]+[elementary-set-theory].

Comment: @AsafKaragila Makes sense, I agree.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Psh! damn. >_< (face palms)

Comment: As ordered sets, $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ are elementarily equivalent to each other and to $\mathbb Q$. Every **countable** densely ordered set without greatest or least element is **isomorphic** to $\mathbb Q$ (Cantor), and **every** densely ordered set without greatest or least element is **elementarily equivalent** to $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Much like @bof says, the two sets have the same first-order theory. So they can only be separated by second-order (or higher) properties. It should be noted that isomorphic structures will satisfy the same first, second, third order properties and so on.

Comment: I see, elementary equivalence will not do the trick. We need *completeness* which is **not** first-order expressible. But it is second-order. We haven't got to second-order logic in our course yet.

Comment: Who's the teacher?

Comment: Samuel Coskey, you know him?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$, the set $[-1, 0)$ has an upper bound, but no least upper bound.  No such set exists in the linearly ordered $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Hey thanks, much appreciated. I should have realized this-- ARG

Comment: I'm guessing this is a second order property? Do you also have an example of two uncountable dense linear orders without endpoints that doesn't satisfy the same first order properties?

Comment: @mvcouwen I am not sure about whether it is first or second order, but I also guess it is second order.  I suggest you ask a new question.

Comment: @mvcouwen I posted your question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/952987/uncountable-dense-linear-orders